# Codeignieter data is not initialized in index function

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am trying to initialize data in index function of controller, so that initialized data can be used in subsequent functions of controller. But the problem is data is not being displayed when I am trying to access it from other function. All of this is just to follow a sort of object oriented pattern.

Here is my code.

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{
    private  $account_data;  /*Declaration*/
    private  $profile_data;

    function __construct() {
       // code...
    }

    function index()   /*Here I am initializing data*/
    {
        $this->load->model('db_model');
        $this->account_data = $this->db_model->get_row();
        $this->profile_data = $this->db_model->get_row();
        $this->load->view('user/dashboard');
    }

    function function account_details()
    {
        print_r($this->account_data);  // This displays nothing
    }

    /*other function...*/

}
```

Idea is to get data once and use it for other functions and if data is updated again calls a function to initialize it.

But it is not working out. Please help me. Also suggest if I am following right approach.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working out ? Should that index be called before account-details ?

Comment: methods in the controllers work in a different executions unless its the constructor OR you call a method from within another method. Here `index` and `account_details`  are accessed in different execution `account_details` wont know about `index`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

index method is not initializer, its default page/sub_method, 
if you call the "*account_details*" in url as `index.php/dashboard/account_details` the index wont be called.

try put the code on constructor,

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{
    private  $account_data;  /*Declaration*/
    private  $profile_data;

    function __construct() { /*Here I am initializing data*/
      parent::CI_Controller(); // Thank you Sven
        $this->load->model('db_model');
        $this->account_data = $this->db_model->get_row();
        $this->profile_data = $this->db_model->get_row();
    }

    function index()   
    {

        $this->load->view('user/dashboard');
    }

    function function account_details()
    {
        print_r($this->account_data);  // This displays nothing
    }

    /*other function...*/

}
```

**Note** : don't the models or other computations on __construct()  if you don't need on all methods of this controller.

create a private method like "`model_initializer()`" put this codes on this scope, and the call it in your other methos as `$this->model_initialize();` if you need.

Thanks yo  Sesama Sesame for note,

Comment: Please also note that leaving the model logic computation inside the controler constructor is not always a good choice.

Comment: Thank you Sesama Sesame  I added a note for custom initializer.

Comment: Thought you need to call the parent (CI_Controller) constructor first or is this obsolete in the new version of CI?

Comment: Oh. Right, I copied the code from question directly. Added now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot you people. Please can you elaborate why it is not a good practice to call modal logic inside constructor.